# how to use find() to return a specific result from another document with ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently working on project,But right now am stock some were,I am trying to find a particular element and get the content,But i don't know were am going wrong because my code is not doing anything,i was able to return every thing in the success message but on able to filter or find a specific element.

```
$(".u_c_n a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   var chatid = this.id;
  //alert(uid);
$.ajax({
  type:'get',
   url:"chat.php",
   data:{chatid:chatid},
   success: function(data){

     $(".msge").html($(data).find("#b").html());
   }
});
});
```

chat.php

```
<div class="chat_box">
    <div class="chat_ibox">
        <div class="chat_upic_o_e"><div><img id="upic" title="upload photo" src="hangout<?php echo $row["photo"];?>"></div>
        <div><img id="chat_option" src="option.jpg"> <img class="chat_exit" id="chat_exit" src="exit.jpg"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="chat_display">

<b id="b">test this work</b>
        </div>
        <div class="chat_typ_txt">
               <form method="" action="">
                      <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type a message">
               </form>
        </div>
        <div class="stic_files">
            <div><img id="chat_stickers" src="option.jpg"> <img id="chat_files" src="exit.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```